# how to configure log4net to work inside a CRM 2011 plugin?

Tags: log4net, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to log some information inside a CRM 2011 plugin. I am not sure how to configure log4net. Where should I put log4net config file and how to reference from the plugin? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are registering your plugins to the database, you have a couple options:

1. Configure log4net programmatically. This can be done via the log4net API and could be driven by a configuration entity in crm.
2. Embed the log4net config file in the plugin assembly and configure log4net from a stream (shown below in a plugin base class that other plugins who wish to log could inherit from)

   ```
   namespace TestPlugins
   {
       public abstract class BaseLoggingPlugin
       {
           protected static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(BaseLoggingPlugin));

           static BaseLoggingPlugin()
           {
               using(var config = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("TestPlugins.log4net.config"))
               {
                   XmlConfigurator.Configure(config);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I used the second approach - embedded config file into assembly. It worked like a charm - thank you!

Comment: 2nd approach for me too! :) I would give +25 if I could :)

Comment: @GregOks I want to do the same, but i am new to log4net and cannot find a detail step by step answer. If u could provide some instructions or demo plugin project. I will be very thankful to you. thanks

Comment: @GregOks I was on another project, in time being. But I am still unable to make it work in plugin.
Please provide a detailed answer and assemblyinfo.cs file details

Comment: @GregOks I have one Imp question also:
How will the logger work, if I register plugin in Database and want to write log files in C drive ??

Comment: @GregOks  I have added the Config file as embedded resource having access modifier public

But I when i open crm i get `Unexpected error`
An error has occurred.

The Event-viewer shows following warning:

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 2/10/2015 4:16:21 AM )

Comment: @GregOks

I have used this approach successfully, but recently i ran into an issue. Some time when a plugin/workflow executes Log File is overwritten.

Comment: @GregOks , First approach worked for me. I want also to try the second approach but how do you embed the log4net config file in the plugin assembly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a warning to whatever the correct answer ends up being:
if you are registering your plugin assembly as a **sandbox** assembly (sandbox mode is required for CRM-online) you will not have access to the file system. In that case, your only option is [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328574.aspx#loggingandtracing). Good luck!

Comment: Fair point @BenPatterson1, even if you are running outside of the sandbox you would need to ensure that the app pool user has access to the directory where you want to write your log files.